# Get checkbox value on form submit and store in a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

Have a form using multiple checkboxes with a class of 'test' (only one of which can be checked however similar to using radio buttons - not my idea btw!).

When the form is submitted I want to get the value of the checkbox that is checked and store it in a variable - can anyone help here?

Cheers!

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var aVariable = $('input.test[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).val();
});
```

`.val()` returns `undefined` if called on an empty jQuery object, which would be the case here if no checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below solution on codebins:

Note: Add latest jquery.js javascript file on header tag first.

HTML:

```
<form id="frm1" method="post">
  <input type="radio" class="test" checked="checked" value="radio1">
  Radio1
  <input type="radio" class="test" checked="checked" value="radio2">
  Radio2
  <input type="radio" class="test" value="radio3">
  Radio3
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="test" checked="checked" value="check1">
  Check1
  <input type="checkbox" class="test" value="check2">
  Check2
  <input type="checkbox" class="test" checked="checked" value="check3">
  Check3
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery within Script tag:

```
$(function() {

    $("#frm1").submit(function() {
        $("input.test[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I have done above bin on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpap

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
$(function() {
    $("#frm1").submit(function() {
        $("input.test[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be good if you could add some explanation of the code - it might be more helpful for other users.

Answer (score -1):

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox');
    var checkedValue=[];
    for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
       console.log(inputElements[i]);
       if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue.push(inputElements[i].value);
       }
    }
alert(checkedValue)
```